# zend Tool error on Ubuntu:- An Error Has Occurred A project already exists here

Tags: zend-tool

I have moved to ubuntu in order to as best as possible duplicate the live server environment for a project i am working on. I used to create my zend folder layouts by hand. But decided to use zend Tool this time. Any way after setting the zf tool up i tried the zf show version command and all went well.

So then i changed directory to a shared folder ( by shared i mean the folder is a fat32 folder that i shared between windows and ubuntu as i dualboot). Anyway i used the command `zf create project .` to create a new project. But i got he error `An Error Has Occurred A project already exists here`. There definitely is no project in that folder. Any way i thought maybe it was a permission issue although i am able to write and read from that folder for all order purposes.

I then tried to create the project again this time in my home folder and still had the same problem. I googled but found only 3 reports of this problem and non of them have been answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue -

ZF doesn't like it when you try and create a project when another one already exists somewhere higher in your directory structure (no-matter the name).

Try looking for old projects in parent directories (specifically .zfproject.xml files), or patch the ZF Project Provider if you want to have a directory structure like this.

[More details here](http://www.danielbyrne.net/2011/02/zend-framework-tool-project-already-exists-here/)

Hope this helps

-Dan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix this problem, you'll have to remove .zfproject.xml. You can find this file by using find /path/to/project -name '.zfproject.xml' and then delete it with  rm -rf /path/to/project/.zfproject.xml.

Hope this help)